# Spintax - TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a spintax article through url scraping. I'm getting a `TypeError` when I integrate a string that I scraped in my spintax (and I did check the type). Other strings are working but not this part of code. So I tried to integrate a "basic" string, and not a string that I scraped, but I have the same `TypeError`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xiaomi\Desktop\spinning_text.py", line 206, in <module>
    "<p>" + long_description2 + "</p>"
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

I also tried that code with `short_description` after `long_description` (instead of before), and then I got the same `TypeError` with `short_description` ...

```
    "<p>" + long_description2 + "</p>\
    <p>" + short_description + "</p>" \n\

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xiaomi\Desktop\spinning_text.py", line 207, in <module>
    <p>" + short_description + "</p> \n\
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

My spintax text is way longer, but here are the basics :

```
    import spintax

    article = ""
    short_description = "short_description"
    long_description = "long_description"
    long_description2 = str(long_description)

    paragraphe ="<p>{Any spintax|Spintax text}.</p> \
    <br><br>\n\
    <p>" + long_description2 + "</p>\
    <p>" + short_description + "</p> \n\

    article = article + paragraphe

    print(spintax.spin(article))
```

When I print article I should have either :

```
"<p>Any spintax</p>
<p>long_description</p>"
```

or

```
"<p>Spintax text</p>
<p>long_description"</p>.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you said "I did check the type" : You printed type(long_description2) ? Have you tried with the str.format() function ?

Comment: I printed the type yes, and it's of course a string... I just tried the str.format() function, and it changed the string into a string and I still got the error... What is weird is if I copy-paste the last line ( <p>" + short_description + "</p>" \n\ ), only the last line has a TypeError.